# How to install 32bit Kubuntu over 64bit Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, reinstall

I have an old system with 2G ram and 64-bit CPU. I installed the X86_64 version of Kubuntu 17.10 on my machine. I am using encrypted LVM volumes. I have decided I would like to try the 32-bit version of 17.10 while keeping my ~/ directory intact if possible.

The installer I have downloaded from Kubuntu seems only to allow a full installation. Is there a good way to accomplish my goals?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to create a backup. With a few remarks:

- you can only restore your personal data
- settings in your `/home/$USER/` you can not use on 32-bit.
- if you want to do this easier next time: create a new partition for your personal data and put your personal data on that partition (this one time you need to restore your backup there). That way you can always mount your data into the new OS (where you can safely format both / and /home).

The "64-bit CPU" should already tell you you should be using a 64-bit operating system. 32-bit is less optimal.

If your reason to install the 32-bit version is due to the 2Gb RAM don't and. The minimal amount is 2Gb and the 32-bit version of kUbuntu will be a worse experience than the 64-bit version. I would suggest installing Ubuntu Mate, lUbuntu or xUbuntu. Those need less resources for the desktop section (even though all have 2 recommended 2Gb RAM).

Comment: My reason for desiring the change is that my system spends more time swapping than it spends performing tasks - or at least seemingly so. Dropping to 32bits would not help that situation?

Comment: @long_time_newbie It wouldn't help that much. Maybe very slightly. Better to buy a bit more RAM then spend the whole day reinstalling with no guarantee that it would work better.